# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'fit' - Pyspark

Tags: python-3.x, pyspark

I am trying to run the script below in PySpark3 and receiving the error message that follows. I am using this has something to do with formatting but I am not sure how to go about doing so. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
train,test = df.randomSplit([0.7,0.3])

models = ["LinearRegression()","DecisionTreeRegressor()","RandomForestRegressor()","GBTRegressor()"]

for model in models:

    # Fit our model
    M = model
    fitModel = M.fit(train)

    # Load the Summary
    trainingSummary = fitModel.summary

#     trainingSummary.residuals.show()
    print("Training RMSE: %f" % trainingSummary.rootMeanSquaredError)
    print("Training r2: %f" % trainingSummary.r2)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-d0b941a7170e> in <module>()
      8     # Fit our model
      9     M = model
---> 10     fitModel = M.fit(train)
     11 
     12     # Load the Summary

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'fit'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this way is actually more efficient....

This way you can still iterate through a list.

```
def ClassTrainEval(model):

    fitModel = model.fit(train)

    # Load the Summary
    trainingSummary = fitModel.summary

    print("Training RMSE: %f" % trainingSummary.rootMeanSquaredError)
    print("Training r2: %f" % trainingSummary.r2)

models = [LogisticRegression(),NaiveBayes(),OneVsRest(),LinearSVC()] 

for model in models:
    ClassTrainEval(classifier)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to modify your models

```
models = [LinearRegression, DecisionTreeRegressor, RandomForestRegressor, GBTRegressor]
```

Because with your current define, they are definitely a string. Better way is to add modules inside list and instance it every loop.

To be precies `models = ["LinearRegression()"]` the element inside is String, not an object which doesn't have any method.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't totally understand your solution Duy. Can you please expand?

Comment: So unfortunately this method will not work. I receive the following error with this method: "NameError: name 'LinearRegression' is not defined" on line 3 where the model list is created.